# spinnaker ecs account wont select

Tags: amazon-ecs, spinnaker

I create and an ecs account name linked to aws account name, enabled ecs. Now when creating a new server group and selecting ecs. Under the account section the ecs account name appears but it wont let me select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spinnaker < `1.19.X` then the AWS ECS provider depends on the AWS EC2 provider and the AWS IAM structure. 
Please read: [AWS Providers Overview](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/aws/) to understand the AWs IAM structure that is required (AWS managing Account and AWS Managed accounts through AssumeRole action)

Then you can set up an AWS EC2 Provider following this easy to g[et started guide by armory](https://docs.armory.io/spinnaker/Armory-Spinnaker-Quickstart-2/#adding-aws-role-to-spinnaker-through-halyard-configuration--note-aws-account-name-is-within-spinnaker-and-will-appear-in-ui)

Finally Set the AWS ECS provider with the [legacy instructions found at spinnaker.io](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/aws/aws-ecs/#legacy-iam-roles-prior-to-119)

If you are using Spinnaker `> 1.19.X` then you must use AWS ECS [Service linked roles](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/aws/aws-ecs/#service-linked-iam-roles)

One very important step is tagging the [AWS VPC subnets](https://docs.armory.io/spinnaker-install-admin-guides/aws-subnets/) so that spinnaker can access them.